# How to make the aync_read and async_write independent to each other while using boost websocket_server_async approach?

Tags: websocket, boost, boost-asio

I'm using boost websocket for my project and stuck with this code where my async_write executes only when it reads something from the client.

I have used this code from [websocket_server_async](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp)

Below is the code

```
void do_read()
{
    // Read a message into our buffer
    ws_.async_read(
        buffer_,
    beast::bind_front_handler(
            &session::on_read,
            shared_from_this()));
}

void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    // This indicates that the session was closed
    if(ec == websocket::error::closed)
    return;

    if(ec)
        fail(ec, "read");

    // Echo the message
    ws_.text(ws_.got_text());
    ws_.async_write(
        buffer_.data(),
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &session::on_write,
            shared_from_this()));
}
```

Here, as async_write is written in `on_read` function this executes only when something is sent from the client. But how can I write message continuously to client by not depending until read is executed

I tried adding a write flag(whenever need to send data to client) and use just `ws_.write` insted of `asyn_write`(Is this a correct way).

```
void do_read()
{
    // Read a message into our buffer
    ws_.async_read(
        client_buffer_,
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &session::on_read,
            shared_from_this()));
    if(write_flag)
    {
        do_write();
    }
}

void do_write()
{
    ws_.write(net::buffer(server_buffer_));
    write_flag = false;

    //Do another read
    do_read();
}

void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    // This indicates that the session was closed
    if(ec == websocket::error::closed)
        return;

    if(ec)
        fail(ec, "read");

    //Do another read
    do_read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make it *independent*. Adding a write flag really cannot help.

Instead make it *literally* independent:

```
do_read_loop() {
     async_read(ws_, buf_, [this, self=shared_from_this](error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
         // ...
         if (!ec)
             do_read_loop();
     });
}
```

On the write side you want the same, except there may not be anything to send at times.

```
std::deque<std::string> outbox_;

do_write_loop() {
     if (outbox_.empty())
         return;

     async_write(ws_, asio::buffer(outbox_.front()), [this, self=shared_from_this](error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
         // ...
         if (!ec) {
             outbox_.pop_front();
             do_write_loop();
         }
     });
}
```

That's it. It's almost completely symmetrical, and completely independent. The only missing part is when to kick of the write-loop.

```
void send(std::string message) {
     outbox_.push_back(std::move(message));
     if (outbox_.size() == 1)
         do_write_loop();
}
```

> For simplicity I have omitted strands (your question also doesn't mention them). If you need them you must make sure the relevant operations are on the strand:
>
> ```
>     void send(std::string msg) {
>         asio::post(ws_.get_executor(),
>              [this, self = shared_from_this(), m = std::move(msg)]() mutable { do_send(std::move(m)); });
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the response, In this case the 2 functions `do_read_loop()` and `do_write_loop()` should be in different threads right? as they are two infinite loops and can u please direct me where can I learn more on this strand concept